# Improving repetitive use of IFs in Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a more efficient approach to this formula?

```
=IF(A1="Texas",1,)&IF(A1="Washington",2,)&IF(A1="Kansas",3,)&IF(A1="California",3,)
```

Simple question, but I'm sure there is a better way then the one I've currently got

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a table in the worksheet and use Vlookup,

[image]

or do it all in one formula like

```
=LOOKUP(A1,{"California","Kansas","Texas","Washington"},{3,3,1,2})
```

The first array must be sorted ascending.

Edit: You can catch errors by wrapping the statement into an IFNA() like this:

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(A1,{"California","Kansas","Texas","Washington"},{3,3,1,2}),"not found")
```

"Shorter" or "more efficient" really depends on your situation. The lookup table is the shortest and it's very quick to add new states to the scenario.

The Lookup formula is fine if the states and their values are not expected to change.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could also use "=INDEX(MATCH(),column)" in your formula. I once read before that it is much faster than using VLookup / HLookup.

Match returns the row of the matched item..